# How to move a single DotNetNuke portal to a new server?

Tags: migration, export, dotnetnuke

I've got a DotNetNuke system (v 5.6) that's hosting several different portals, and I'd like to move one of them to another hosting provider.  What's the easiest way to do this?

Every web site I find that claims to explain how to move a DotNetNuke site essentially says "Copy the entire database over to the new system."  That's great if you've only got one portal in the database, but I've got a dozen of them.  I only want to move one portal, not all of them.

Exporting the site to a .template is another popular suggestion.  This exports the structure of the site (all the tab definitions, for example), but it doesn't include any of the actual HTML content.  As such, that's essentially worthless.

There must be a reasonable way to do this short of trying to strip one individual portals data out of every single DNN table.  Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, I did find a solution from someone over on the [DotNetNuke forums](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/107/postid/473498/scope/posts.aspx).

> Create a 2nd version of that install, then delete all the other
>   portals. Move the install with the one portal. We've done this several
>   times with installs with lots of portals and it works just fine. Yeah
>   there's still some noise left in the db, but it's a quick and
>   effective way of doing things.
>
> *Edit* note that this will give you an install with 1 portal. You can't detach a portal from one install  and reattach it to an existing
>   install (well, you can, but basically you have to export the portal as
>   a template and that isn't 100%)

This is the approach I took, and sure enough, it works.

In a nutshell:

1. Mirror the files for the web site to another server.
2. Mirror the DNN database to another server.
3. Log in a Host on the new setup and delete all the portals but the one you want to migrate.
4. Delete any module definitions that are not in use by the remaining portal.
5. Open up your favorite SQL tool and delete any entries in the `Users` and `UserProfile` tables that no longer have a matching row in the `UserPortals` table. DNN does not remove these by default, which is frustrating.
6. Hop in to Windows Explorer and delete all of the Portal folders you no longer need (ie: /Portal/1, /Portal/2, etc.)
7. Back up the database using Enterprise Manager to create a .bak file
8. Make a .zip of the entire DNN installation folder.

You now have a .bak that contains the database and a .zip that contains the files.  Send those off to the new hosting company, and you should be all set.  Just make sure to update your `web.config` to set the connection string properly to point to the new database server at the new hosting company.

It's just that easy.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

When you export a site template, you can include the content of the site, as well (for the modules that support portability, which includes the standard HTML module).  This is how the default site template has all of its content.  When you do this, there will be a `.template.resources` file that you'll need, as well as the `.template` file.

The other option is to do a full backup and restore, and then remove the other sites once you've restored.  If you have significant content in a module that doesn't support portability, I think this will be your best bet.

Comment: Just be aware that you will be able to import such exported templates only on another DNN host that is same DNN version.

Comment: Really?  Same DNN version?  That's quite limiting!